# HTMLElement triggers a function in another HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component

I have a hamburger button and a menu in an `HTMLElement` class.

When the screen width is less than 912 pixels, the menu is translated 100% to the left (off screen) and the hamburger appears. When I click the button, the menu is brought back on screen.

**I want to separate the hamburger and the menu into their own `HTMLElement` classes.** That means I need a click on the hamburger to cause a change in the menu's style. The problem is the `shadowRoot`. If not for the shadow root, I could add a transform to the menu style, but it's not possible.

How can I separate the two classes? Is there a way I can call a function inside the menu `HTMLElement` class from an outer `HTML` file? That way, I can work around the shadowRoot?

Here is the code for the working class:

```
const myMenuTemplate = document.createElement('template');
myMenuTemplate.innerHTML = `
<style>

  * {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }

  .my-button {
    margin-left: 16px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .my-button div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #34515e;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  .my-menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 90vh;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 912px){

    body{
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .my-button{
      display: block;
    }

    .my-menu{
      transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
  }

  .toggle-button .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 0px) scaleX(0.6);
  }

  .toggle-button .line2{
    transform: translate(5px, 0px)
  }

  .toggle-button .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, 0px) scaleX(0.6);
  }

  .toggle-menu {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }

</style>

<div class="my-button">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</div>

<ul class="my-menu">
  <slot/>
</ul>
`;


class MyMenu extends HTMLElement{
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open'});
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(myMenuTemplate.content.cloneNode(true)); 

    const myMenu = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.my-menu');
    const myButton = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.my-button');

    myButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      myButton.classList.toggle('toggle-button');
      myMenu.classList.toggle('toggle-menu');
    });
  }
}

window.customElements.define("my-menu", MyMenu);
```

Comment: I have considered two options: (1) A lambda function with a parameter of type Element, so I can access the shadowRoot; or (2) some script that can be called from an external HTML file.

Comment: please provide a code example

Comment: Use [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) to create 'communication' between Components